# twitter bootstrap fluid layout 3 columns

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, fluid-layout

excuse for dummy question.
I need to create 3 fluid columns layout using twitter bootstrap.
First column is 45% of page width, 
second is 10%
the third should be 45% of page width.

I've tried this:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span5">
            <table class="table table-bordered">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>#</th>
                    <th>First Name</th>
                    <th>Last Name</th>
                    <th>Username</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td>Jacob</td>
                    <td>Thornton</td>
                    <td>@fat</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>3</td>
                    <td colspan="2">Larry the Bird</td>
                    <td>@twitter</td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="span2"></div>
        <div class="span5">
            <table class="table table-bordered">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>#</th>
                    <th>First Name</th>
                    <th>Last Name</th>
                    <th>Username</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td>Jacob</td>
                    <td>Thornton</td>
                    <td>@fat</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>3</td>
                    <td colspan="2">Larry the Bird</td>
                    <td>@twitter</td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

But the middle column is too wide, it's not 10% of screen width.
Please help me to get the ide of fluid layout in twitter bootstrap.

Answer (score 2):

In Twitter Bootstrap with a 12-column fluid layout a `span2` has `width: 14.5299%` and a `span5` has `width: 40.1709%`.

It's a consequence of dividing the media width in 12 columns and its gutters.

If you need a diferent distribution you can customize your layout here: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/customize.html

Comment: I've seen this page, but I don't understand how to break these columns 45/10/45. I've opened generated bootstrap.css file and see there hardcoded pixel values for .spanXX width

Comment: There are pixel values for fixed layouts and percent values for fluid layouts.

Comment: Sorry, seems like I'm dumb. http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/customize.html#components - has fixed px values by default in variables for columns width. Do I have to input 45% instead of integer number?

Comment: No, first find percent values for column, gutter, and number of columns that fit your needs (that's the hard stage, math stuff). Then you can choose any pixel values that mantain the same ratios as the percents.

Answer (score 0):

If you need that ratio, just change the BS grid system from a 12 columns to 20 columns. Then use span9, span2, span9.

But this won't make exactly 45/10/45 percents. Since BS has gutters...